# How to update href with ui-sref when parameters change Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an element like so

```
<a ui-sref="State.child"></a>
```

I then go to the state that contains this template and my url looks like so

```
http://url?q=query
```

I can click on the link and it works as expected. Inspecting it shows that the href attribute looks like

```
href='/child?q=query'
```

However in my state it is possible to update my state by changing the q param. eg.

```
http://url?q=newquery
```

but the href in the  tag still has the old value of q. Is there anyway to update this value?

Comment: a directive that listens to a stateChange event would work for you...or listen for changes to $location.search()

Comment: you could do change your state by `$state.go('State.child',{q: 'newquery'})`

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll have to do one of these, I was hoping there was a flag I could set or something to have this done automatically